# Single-quoted chars and double-quoted strings

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am studying parsers and lexers with ANTLR4. I wanna keep chars (single chars) single quoted and strings (more than one char) double-quoted, but I am kinda new into regex and I cannot do this, so I would like some examples, also, I am having some problems with quotes inside my regex statements in ANTLR4.

For example, it should accept only the following regarding strings and chars:

```
mychar = 'a'; // Chars single-quoted and single-char'd.
mystring = "test"; // Strings with MORE THAN ONE CHARS and double-quoted.
```

Comment: Since ANTLR4 doesn't use regular expressions, I wonder if this question is about REs or ANTLR4, actually?

Comment: Well, I'd say ANTLR's lexer grammar uses regular expressions. Just not the same as regular expression implementations (often PCRE) used in (modern) programming languages (which are not "regular").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this for a single quoted char:

```
CHAR
 : '\'' ( '\\' ~[\r\n] | ~[\\'\r\n] ) '\''
 ;
```

where `'\\' ~[\r\n]` matches an escaped char (but not an escaped line break char) and `~[\\'\r\n]` matches a char other than `\\`, `'` and a line break char.

And a pretty similar double quoted rule:

```
STRING
 : '"' ( '\\' ~[\r\n] | ~[\\"\r\n] )* '"'
 ;
```

Comment: Good. Thanks. Just a little issue: It looks like to be accepting unquoted string and char value definitions.

Comment: Both my rules start with a quote, so it is impossible for either `CHAR` or `STRING` to be accepting any unquoted input. If you lexer accepts unquoted input, then it's one of your other rules that does so.

Comment: You're right, there was another rule of mine messing with this.